# Spring-Boot Vaadin deploy project on jetty

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, vaadin

How to deploy a Spring boot vaadin project on jetty using intellij, the Idea behind that is to refresh the project after each changes without restarting the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the people who downvote a question without answering it. however here is the answer:

in Spring framework using spring-dev-tools, you have the option to deploy the project whenever the class path changes( in intellij the class path change event is triggered when we rebuild the project, in eclipse class path change event is triggered as soon as we hit the save file of any class). Server will restart (tomcat or jetty) and load the project (Restart method).

we could overcome this expensive approach using third party plug-ins  such as JRebel. JRebel will only deploy the class that has been changed.

consider developing a web app and consider making about 100 runs a day, everytime the server restarts it consumes 3 seconds. do the math